# Getting RFID-RC522 to work with Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: rfid

Yesterday I bought the famous RC552 RFID read/write module to use with my Raspberry Pi 2B (I've also got an Arduino in the mail right now) and I've been trying to get it to work but I just can't.
I started by installing `python-dev`. I then installed SPI-PY by downloading it from GitHub (`https://github.com/lthiery/SPI-Py`) and used `sudo python setup.py install` to install it. 
I then connected the module to my Pi using this diagram:
[image]

Then, I downloaded this library from GitHub (`https://github.com/mxgxw/MFRC522-python`) and ran the `Read.py` example application to try it out. Upon doing so, I got the following message: `can't open device: no such file or directory`. The program then halted. I tested to see if it was a line of code causing the problem, by placing the command `print "Test"` at the top of the document. I saw the following:

```
Test
can't open device: no such file or directory
```

I definitely know it's something in the code now. I moved my print command down the document, until it was under this line:

```
MIFAREReader = MFRC522.MFRC522()
```

Once it was under this, I only saw the error message. So I know it's this line.

I decided to try a different project, so I downloaded this one (`https://github.com/ondryaso/pi-rc522`). I ran the `Read.py`, but got the same message. 
What's going on? Did I do something wrong? Your help would be greatly appreciated.

*Apologies for putting the links as code, the editor said I couldn't post more than 2 links because my rep is below 10.*

Comment: At a guess the SPI devices aren't present so leading to can't open device: no such file or directory.  Could you edit your question and add the result of "ls -l /dev/spi*" without the quotes.  Similarly add the result of "uname -a" and "cat /etc/os-release".

Comment: Also, can you double-check your wiring? The diagram you use has the correct wiring, but a simple mistake can be enough for SPI to not recognize a device. Make sure you have the orientation of the GPIO header correct - pin 1 is located close to where the SD card goes, with pin 40 close to the USB ports. Early rPi's (model A/B) had a marking on the board next to P1 but this has been dropped on the rPi 2 model B.

Comment: joan - the result of `ls -l /dev/spi` tells me that `/dev/spi` doesn't exist. Maybe that's where the error is coming from? `uname -a` gives `Linux raspberrypi 4.1.7-v7+ #817 SMP PREEMPT Sat Sep 19 15:32:00 BST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux` and `cat /etc/os-release` gives `PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"`
`NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"`
`VERSION_ID="8"`
`VERSION="8 (jessie)"`
`ID=raspbian`
`ID_LIKE=debian`
`HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"`
`SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"`
`BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"`

Comment: I have found this to be a great related article ... http://raspmer.blogspot.de/2015/07/how-to-use-rfid-rc522-on-raspbian.html

Answer (score 3):

> Make sure the SPI Interface is enabled:

Edit the file /boot/config.txt and add the following two lines:

```
device_tree_param=spi=on
dtoverlay=spi-bcm2708
```

Reboot the Pi and check if the SPI Interface software is running:

```
$ dmesg | grep spi
```

You should see something like:

```
[    8.577659] bcm2708_spi 20204000.spi: master is unqueued, this is deprecated
[    8.578491] bcm2708_spi 20204000.spi: SPI Controller at 0x20204000 (irq 80)
```

You can also check:

```
$ lsmod
```

which should list:

```
spi_bcm2708             5429  0
```

I found this solution [here](http://raspmer.blogspot.de/2015/07/how-to-use-rfid-rc522-on-raspbian.html) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To get this working, the easiest is to fire up the graphical environment and go to menu->Preferences->Raspberry Pi configuration and there enable in the interface tab the spi line....

the diagram you show is for the old raspberries, the new one have 40pins, not 25

Comment: Hello and welcome to rpi.se. Most of this is probably better suited as a comment than as an answer. Answers should not be used for requesting additional information from the questioner - that is better suited as a comment, nor to open a discussion about possible solutions - that is better suited as a chat. Consider editing your answer so that it is an answer to the question, and move the other parts.